# Connecting camera to the iPad2

Tags: ipad, camera

I want to connect a camera (web cam or just regular digital camera) to the iPad and download the pictures from the camera and showing it on the iPad. I need it to be live - take a picture with the camera and than download it from the camera into the iPad. any suggestions?
Is there a way to connect the camera to the iPad and connect the power supply of the iPad at the same time (the iPad should be connected to power supply all the time).

if it is not possible is there any other tablets which can make these requirements?

Thanks in advance,
Shahar.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't get "live" because the camera needs to be put into transfer mode (or at least my Canons and Panasonic camera does, maybe not all).  The Camera Connection Kit will allow connection of a camera to the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible with the iPad2 see [iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://www.apple.com/ipad/accessories/#camera-connection)

and also with the Galaxy Tab 10.1 [Galaxy Tab™ Adapter (USB)](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab-accessories/EPL-1PL0BEGSTA)

Comment: but as a developer do I have an sdk for using the camera download the picture myself and use it as a part of my app?

Comment: The Camera Connection Kit does not do "live" transfers.  They have to be initiated, after the camera is put into transfer mode.

Answer (score 1):

How about buying an [Eye-Fi](http://uk.eye.fi/) memory card. It's memory cards with Wifi built in. With [Direct Mode](http://uk.eye.fi/how-it-works/features/direct-mode) you should be able to transfer the pictures on the fly.

Make sure you check that the card you buy is Direct Mode compatible by studying their [compare cards](http://uk.eye.fi/products/compare-cards) chart.